# Misma font-family en toda la página

Tags: html5, css3, fuentes

Tengo definido entre otras propiedades

```
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

No hay ninguna referencia más en toda la página a cambios de fuente ni nada similar, y aparentemente se establece bien la propiedad para toda la página, pero en los input y en los botones cambia la fuente automáticamente y pone la Arial, tachando la que yo le "impongo" desde el body

[image: Pantalla depuración]

Forzando cada elemento lo podría conseguir, pero la pregunta es, ¿por qué no hereda correctamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que los elementos tipo `input` tienen su propia especificación de fuente de acuerdo a la hoja de estilos global que aplica el navegador.

Por lo tanto si deseas que tus elementos tipo `input` tengan la misma familia de fuente que el elemento `body`, podrias hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

**styles.css**

```
body, input {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Así, todos los elementos tipo `input` de tu documento usarán la familia de fuentes establecida en tu hoja de estilos.

También podrías usar algo como:

```
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
input {
    font-family: inherit;
}
```

Así podrías entonces aplicar diferentes fuentes envolviendo tu elemento `input` en algún contenedor que tenga una fuente diferente a la establecida para `body`.

Espero que sea la respuesta que buscabas.

Comment: ¿Hay algún sitio/documento donde se puedan buscar/encontrar esos detalles que ocurren con los diferentes elementos?